# Would like to combine two columns of data, one has blank rows, other is continuous

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns of data in excel: A & B. The first column (A) has zeros and blank cells. The second column (B) has numbers. I would like to make a third column (C) that enters the numbers from column two sequentially into the blank spaces from the first column.

I was thinking i could use: =if(A1="",B1, A1) but that obviously will be wrong if the first blank is at A3 since B3 will be entered.
I think i need a command to move down the B1 column only if it gets entered into A.

```
     A  B  C 
 1.  0  24  0
 2.  0  13  0
 3.     41  24 
 4.     62  13 
 5.  0  6   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting question.

Try this....and please don't forget to accept the solution if it works for you.  I am trying to increase my reputation here since I am new to StackOverflow.  Thanks!

```
Assuming Excel Sheet looks like following:
Cell A1 = 0 Cell B1 = 24
Cell A2 = 0 Cell B2 = 13
Cell A3 =   Cell B3 = 41
Cell A4 =   Cell B4 = 62
Cell A5 = 0 Cell B5 = 6

Type this in cell C1: 

=IF(A1="",INDEX($B$1:$B$5,SUM(($A$1:A1="")*(1))),"")
```

make sure to push control-shift-enter when submitting the formula in cell C1 since it is an array formula.  You should then be able to copy it (control-c) and paste it down the remaining rows (control-v)

Comment: Great!  Glad I could help!